# Characteristic cycle of Laumon's sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Recently I'm reading about the construction of automorphic sheaves for GLn, and I would like to see how to determine the characteristic variety of Laumon's sheaf, since it carries some information about the automorphic sheaf. It does not seem to be straightforward(largely due to my imperfect understanding about characteristic cycles).Is there any reference about calculations of this kind?